# Invoking powershell show-command from a batch script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to give helpdesk staff who are not familiar with Powershell the ability to run one-off Powershell functions by just executing a batch file. In the batch file I launch powershell with bypass executionpolicy, import and run the function. Additionally, I wanted to use Show-Command to give them a graphical UI that would make the parameters more obvious. This runs, but apparently any code that is invoked with the & operator runs in its own child scope. This means when the command with arguments is returned to the "parent" Powershell window, it will have lost knowledge of the function that was imported inside the child scope. Here's what I have in the batch file:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -noexit -executionpolicy bypass -command "& {. \\server\share\New-DriveRemapScript.ps1;Show-Command New-DriveRemapScript}"
```

The launched Powershell windows remains, but when I hit enter on the command text returned by Show-Command, I get "New-DriveRemapScript : The term 'New-DriveRemapScript' is not recognized ...."

Answer (score 0):

Try using `-File` - this is best if you want to launch a single powershell script.

```
powershell.exe -File "\\server\share\New-DriveRemapScript.ps1" -ExecutionPolicy Bypass
```

then in `New-DriveRemapScript.ps1` which probably just contains:

```
Function New-DriveRemapScript {
...
}
```

at the end add in

`Show-Command New-DriveRemapScript`

this will ensure the command is loaded and then executed when the file is called.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to make this work without having to "run" the function within my script file. This way the function file can be shared with savvy Powershell users as well who know how to dot source things in their profile. I don't have a perfect solution, but my *workaround* was to define the function as Global (Global:New-DriveRemapScript), so that it would still be available after the child scope exits. Then the above batch file code works as expected.